# Как проверить, есть ли строка в множестве?

Tags: delphi

Не могу понять в чем дело, делаю так

```
class function TGetTCPRespons.RequestPars(ClientReq: String): TTcpRequest;
type
  TCommands = (login, ping, settings, event);
var
  Commands: set of TCommands;
  SubList: TStringList;
begin
...
if SubList[1] in Cоmmands then
```

> Operator not applicable to this operand type в последней строке

Давал другое название вместо `Command` и переменной и типу, менял в условии `SubList[1]` на 'asdfg' и на строковую переменную, все равно та же ошибка.

Comment: Делфи с множествами *так* не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все верно. В Delphi нельзя просто так взять и сравнить строку с элементом перечисления или множеством.

Как быть?
Сначала приводите свою строку к элементу перечисления, а потом уже проверяйте, есть он во множестве или нет.

```
const
  CommandsStr: array [TCommands] of string = ('login', 'ping', 'settings', 'event');

..

function StringToCommands(aString: string): TCommands;
var
  I: TCommands;
begin
  for I := Low(TCommands) to High(TCommands) do
    if CommandsStr[I] = aString then
      Exit(I);

  Assert(False, '"' + aString + '" can not be converted to TCommands');
end;

..

if StringToCommands(SubList[1]) in Cоmmands then
```

Так как вы проверяете лишь принадлежность строки к возможным элементам перечисления, вам будет достаточно использовать функцию `StringToCommands`, заменив возврат на булевый, и `Assert` на возврат False.

```
function StringInCommands(aString: string): Boolean;
var
  I: TCommands;
begin
  for I := Low(TCommands) to High(TCommands) do
    if CommandsStr[I] = aString then
      Exit(True);

  Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: "_приводите свою строку к элементу перечисления_" где вы тут приводите строку к перечислению?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 потому что  элементы перечисления это константы, их имена должны быть уникальны.

Comment: @teran ошибка терминологии. Имеется ввиду перевести строку в перечислению

Answer (score 6):

В модуле `TypInfo` есть две основные функции для работы со значениями перечислений. Это функция `GetEnumName()`, возвращающая строковое представления значения, и `GetEnumValue`, возвращающая значение по строке.

Допустим, ваше перечисление имеет следующий вид:

```
type
    TMyCommand = (mcCut, mcCopy, mcDelete, cmPaste);
```

и следующий набор переменных:

```
var mc : set of TMyCommand;   // множество 
    sl : TStringList;         // строки 
    s : string;               // итерации по строке
    c : TMyCommand;           // элемент перечисления
```

Вы задаете следующий список строк и множество:

```
sl := TStringList.Create();
sl.CommaText := 'copy,delete,move,redo,cut';

mc := [mcCut, mcDelete];
```

Далее вы хотите пройтись по строковому списку и определить, есть ли элементы во множестве. Для этого вы сначала с помощью `getEnumValue` приводите строку к типу `TMyCommand`, а затем проверяете, есть ли она во множестве.

```
for s in sl do begin
    c := TMyCommand(getEnumValue(typeinfo(TMyCommand), 'mc' + s));

    writeln(s, #9'-'#9, msgs[c in mc]);
end;
```

где `msgs` это массив сообщений для вывода:

```
const msgs : array[boolean] of string = ('not in set', 'in set');
```

---

***Для ликбеза:***

- по большому счету элементы перечислений — это целочисленные константы (по сей причине, они легко приводятся к byte/integer и обратно, а само множество можно привести к типу `TIntegerSet`). В связи с этим константы должны иметь уникальные имена.
- Для этой уникальности общепринято добавлять к названию значения префиксы. Префикс составляют из заглавных букв имени перечисления. Само наименование типа перечисления, конечно же, начинают с префикса `T`. Таким образом, `TMyCommand` дает префикс `mc`, `TTypeKind` (из `typinfo`) -  `tk`, и так далее.
- С появлением фреймворка FireMonkey, указание полного названия при использовании значений перечислений практически стало обязательным, т.е. теперь принято писать `c := TMyCommand.mcCopy`.
- Данное поведение регулируется директивой компилятора `{$SCOPEDEUNMS ON/OFF}`.
- Множество само по себе может содержать до 256 элементов, но это поведение можно изменить в настройках компилятора.
- Обычно значения перечисления последовательны: 0,1,2... но можно также их задать и в явном виде `TMyTest = (mtTest = 4, mtTest = 20)`. Однако в таком случае `RTTI`- информация для перечисления не генерируется.

Comment: Если честно, не понял. Например, " с помощью getEnumName приводите строку к типу TMyCommand "

Comment: @ArtGrek13 в примере кода далее все ведь написано. Есть у вас строка `s = 'copy'`, вы из этой строки хотите получить `TMyCommand.mcCopy`. Для  этого, прибавляете к строке префикс `mc`, находите соответствующее значение перечисления `getEnumValue(typeinfo(TMyCommand), 'mc' + s)` и явно приводите его у типу `TMyCommand`.

Comment: я нашел пример http://mycpp.ru/delphi/help/name.php?name=TypeInfo, пробую Form1.Caption := SetToString(TypeInfo(TFontStyles).Control.Font.Style);, выдает ошибку Record, object or class type required и 'END' expected but ')' found

Comment: Может модуля нет какого то? ошибка в  словах "Control" "Font" "Style"

Comment: запятая там перед Control должна быть, а не точка. и `uses typinfo;` скорее всего

Comment: Делал, но Undeclared identifier: 'Control'

Comment: дак замените его на контрол который вам нужен, `form1`, `button22` и т.п.

Comment: Делал и так тоже SetToString(TypeInfo(TFontStyles), Button1.Font.Style);  Variable required

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Узнал что то новое, **teran** +, но сейчас мне легче сделать так

```
class function TGetTCPRespons.RequestPars(ClientReq: String): TTcpRequest;
const
  Commands: String = 'login,ping,settings,event';

var
  SubList: TStringList; 

  function StringInArr(aVal, aArr: String): Boolean;
  var
    i: Integer;
    iSL: TStringList;
  begin
    iSL := TStringList.Create;
    iSL.DelimitedText := aArr;
    for i := 0 to iSL.Count - 1 do
      if aVal = iSL[i] then
      begin
        iSL.Free;
        Exit(True);
      end;
    iSL.Free;
    Result := False;
  end;
begin

  if StringInArr(SubList[1], Commands) then ...
```

Comment: `iSL.Free`? (1 символ нужен...)

Comment: забыл,спасибо, добавлю)

Comment: Давайте тогда уж проще: `Commands: String = ',login,ping,settings,event,';` `result := Pos(','+aVal+',',aArr) > 0;`

Comment: @Igor если так то if  Pos(SubList[1], Commands)  <> 0 then

Comment: да, если Вы уверены, что в `Commands` не будет значений, являющихся подстрокой другого значения

Comment: Вот интересно а что быстрее Pos() или перебрать список, думаю второе, если строка не маленькая

Comment: @Igor "подстрокой другого значения", в запросе приходит пара command:login, если имя command идет проверка значения на то что это допустимая команда

Comment: `result := (iSL.indexOf(aVal) >= 0);` и все.

Comment: @teran, а если нет совпадения -1?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 [да](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStringList_IndexOf.html)

Comment: @Igor "Pos(','+aVal+',',aArr)" так все таки правильнее, исключает "gin,pi"

Comment: @ArtGrek13 я, собственно, это и имел в виду в комментарии выше